# Inverse of an essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be analytic in $0< |z-z_0| <r$ and suppose that $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$. Let $w$ be any complex number. Show that $$
> g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)-w}\quad z \in D
> $$ is not bounded in any punctured disk $0< |z-z_0| <\varepsilon$.

I'm thinking of approaching it by contradiction, assuming $g$ is bounded, but I haven't gotten farther than that.

Comment: What do you know about the behaviour of holomorphic functions near an isolated singularity? Especially if the function is bounded?

Comment: See [Casorati-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You have to use argument by contradiction. In fact, this result is so-called Weierstrass's Theorem. Suppose $|g(z)|\le M$ ($M>0$) in $0<|z-z_0|<\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Then $|f(z)-w|>\frac{1}{M}$ in $0<|z-z_0|<\varepsilon$. Define
$$ F(z)=\frac{f(z)-w}{z-z_0}. $$
Then $F(z)$ is analytic in $0<|z-z_0|<\varepsilon$ and moreover 
$$ \lim_{z\to z_0}F(z)=\infty. $$
The latter means that $z=z_0$ is a pole of $F(z)$ and hence $F(z)$ can be expressed as the following form
$$ F(z)=\frac{c_{-m}}{(z-z_0)^m}+\cdots+\frac{c_{-1}}{z-z_0}+c_0+c_1(z-z_0)+\cdots. $$
Therefore
$$ f(z)=\frac{c_{-m}}{(z-z_0)^{m-1}}+\cdots+\frac{c_{-2}}{z-z_0}+(A+c_{-1})+c_0(z-z_0)+\cdots. $$
From this, one can see that $z=z_0$ is a pole of $f(z)$ if $m>1$ or a removable singularity if $m=1$, which is contradictory to the assumption.

Comment: Im assuming $A=w$?

Comment: @user71854 Yes, it is. It should be $w$ instead of $A$. Sorry about that.